# Active Directory User Check

Tags: security, active-directory, user-accounts

When I'm trying to logon with wrong password on expired account, AD generates an error. Sometimes the error says "Account expired" and sometimes "Bad user name or password".

In what order does AD check user's attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first be told that the username and password are incorrect, you will only be told the account is expired if the username and password are correct.

Comment: I'm always logon with **wrong** password on **expired** account and AD generates different errors. In most case the error says "Account expired", but sometimes "Bad user name or password"

Comment: @ДмитрийСтепанов Can you post your code/test then because this isn't normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

All work fine now. We got different errors because secondary DC is out of sync.